# Assets not rendering in production rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-api

I have precompiled the assets in production but the application is not able to load the assets. My app is deployed on AWS EC2

[image]

I checked in the server in public/assets folder the application.css is present. [image]
 but still it says 404 error.

My production.rb configuration is

[image]

My nginx.conf settings are: [image]

Comment: What kind of environment is "production" (heroku, aws, etc)

Comment: Its deployed on AWS ec2

Comment: What's your web server (nginx?) configuration looking like?

Comment: I am not sure Where should i look for that?

Comment: It'd be a nginx.conf file, probably in your /config folder.

Comment: I have updated the nginx.conf settings

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem

set `config.assets.compile = True`

It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

The 404 is based on that line in your config: `config.serve_static_files =  true`. That might be the wrong name depending on your rails version. I believe that setting is named `config.serve_static_assets` in Rails prior to version 5.

If you don't have a server (nginx/etc) then you want that setting to be true. Otherwise you need to reconfigure your server to point at your /public directory, and make sure `rake assets:precompile` runs successfully.

Comment: I have nginx server on ec2. should i make it true or false?

Comment: Set it to false. "true" means rails will serve files, "false" means something else (nginx) will serve files. But you also have to make sure your nginx config points to the "public" directory of your rails app.

Comment: Thanks a lot @RiptheJacker. I checked my nginx.conf file and pointed the root with correct public path and it resolved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was my configuration in nginx of root path was wrong. so assets were not pointing to wrong path.

I changed in nginx.conf:

from `root /home/deploy/appname/public`
to `root /home/deploy/appname/current/public`

AND in production.rb

`config.serve_static_assets = true` to `config.serve_static_assets = false`

Answer (score 0):

I did the same as you:

```
root /home/deploy/appname/public root  => /home/deploy/appname/current/public
```

And that works for me. With the unique difference that i left the **config/production.rb** file like this:

```
config.public_file_server.enabled = true

config.assets.compile = true
```

I'm using Rails 5.